# On the "spectrum" of an operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Very simple question, I'm new to this. I'm reading Griffiths book on QM and have a question about the "spectrum" of an observable operator. Does the spectrum of an operator require specification of a particular system? Or is the spectrum of an operator just every possible eigenvalue that can be obtained by every possible eigenfunction of an operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectrum of a particular operator is the set of all possible eigen values.

In regards to the other answer: since the Hamiltonian of a system has a different form for different systems, also the spectrum of that Hamiltonian will vary with different systems. So talking about the spectrum of *a Hamiltonian* is equivalent to “the set of all possible energies a system can have”. However, once you specify that it’s the Hamiltonian of a harmonic oscillator, this fixed the shape of $H$ and therefore its spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the spectrum of an operator depends on the *Hilbert space* (= space of possible wavefunctions) on which it is defined. For example, the Hamiltonian for a free particle in one dimension $H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ has eigenvalues that depend on the boundary conditions for the wavefunction $\psi$. In a box (= infinite potential well) of length $a$, the eigenvalues are $E_n = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}\right)^2$ which depend on $a$, even though the expression for the operator does not. For the same operator without any boundary conditions, any real number is an eigenvalue.

The Hamiltonian is a special operator because it *defines* the system. A "system" is nothing more than a choice of Hilbert space and a Hamiltonian defined on it. The spectrum of other operators, such as position $x$ and momentum $p = \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, depends on the Hilbert space but not on the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

Each operator has it's own spectrum. For the hamiltonian the spectrum is the set of allowed energy levels. This depends on masses and potentials.

Comment: So the spectrum of the Hamiltonian *requires* the specification of a particular system. The Hamiltonian operator by itself does not have a spectrum? Is this the case for all operators or have I misunderstood?

Comment: There are many different Hamiltonians. One for each quantum system. The hamiltonian of the hydrogen atom, or of iron are very different operators. As is the hamiltonian of crystal of copper, or a spin in a magnetic field. All different.

Comment: So the spectrum of the Hamiltonian is *different* in each of these cases? In other words it is not meaningful to talk of the spectrum of an operator unless you additionally specify a particular system?

Comment: Each different hamiltonioan is a different operator, with a different spectrum.